# Request entity expected but not supplied inside postman

Tags: spray, postman

the http POST method request is not working in the Postman

```
localhost:9090/user/approve?userId=1467279168878
```

In headers i added one field `Access_Token`.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this message when I tried to do a POST on a record that was already existing in DB. Try removing this item or using PUT.

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion but it doesn't work for me.